# Find all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = \sin(ax) + e^{bx^2} $is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

What I tried so far:

- using the definition of convexity → very general, not really good to use?
- calculate $f''(x)$ and find $a, b$ such that $ f''(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x$ → difficult to find all $a,b$ such that it is always positive.

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= a \cdot \cos(ax) + 2xb \cdot  e^{bx^2}  \\
f''(x) &= -a^2 \cdot \sin(ax) + 4 x^2 b^2 \cdot e^{bx^2} + 2b \cdot  e^{bx^2} \\
&= -a^2 \cdot \sin(ax) + e^{bx^2}\cdot (4 x^2b^2 + 2b)
\end{align}

Is there anything else that I could / should try when proving convexity?

Comment: Can you show us your calculation of $f''$ ?

Comment: There are a few things you can conclude without calculations... no $b < 0 $ will work, and $b = 0$ only works if $a=0$.

Comment: where did you get this qn from?

Comment: I think it was an old exam question in calculus 1